# Very Slow Booting After apt-get upgrade

Tags: boot

Last night, I update my EOS by using `sudo apt-get upgrade`. After that, my boot time is very very slow. Usually take 5 second, now ~1 minutes (I using SSD). In terminal, I run `systemd-analyze blame` and this is the result:

```
         52.435s lvm2-monitor.service
          6.056s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
           646ms snapd.service
           519ms dev-sdb6.device
           430ms pantheon-parental-controls.service
           399ms systemd-logind.service
           346ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b0250d61\x2d5041\x2d478b\x2daf87\x2d85a390dcef9c.swap
           327ms snapd.seeded.service
           287ms lightdm.service
           287ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
           216ms systemd-resolved.service
           211ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           192ms NetworkManager.service
           171ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           143ms upower.service
           134ms networkd-dispatcher.service
           121ms udisks2.service
           117ms systemd-udevd.service
```

Thats lvm2 is crazy, how to fix this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using [LVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3596/what-is-lvm-and-what-is-it-used-for), you can try masking the service:

```
sudo systemctl disable lvm2-monitor.service
sudo systemctl mask lvm2-monitor.service
```

To determine whether you use LVM partitions, run:

```
sudo lvdisplay --verbose
```

To undo the disable/mask commands, run:

```
sudo systemctl unmask lvm2-monitor.service
sudo systemctl enable lvm2-monitor.service
```

OFF TOPIC: If you do not need [NetworkManager-wait-online.service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do), you can disable and mask it as well. Get those precious seconds back!

Comment: I run that command, now when I check in ```systemd-analyze blame```, lvm2 is not annoying anymore, but another service take more time. ```4.142s udisks2.service``` and ```1.178s dev-sdb6.device```

Comment: When I run ```systemd-analyze``` command, this is the result ```Startup finished in 43.088s (kernel) + 5.708s (userspace) = 48.796s
graphical.target reached after 5.703s in userspace```

Comment: Looks like it's waiting on a disk drive. Let's dig in deeper then: please edit your question and add the output of the following commands: `lsblk -f`, `cat /etc/fstab` and `sudo lvdisplay --verbose`.

Comment: Thanks very much, with your explanation, I know that my SD card is attached to my laptop, and I don't know why my SD card is little bit broken. I know that issue when I run ```sudo lvdisplay --verbose```. Now my EOS back to normal :)

Comment: Glad I could help! And thank you for letting us know which command helped.